# При добавлении товара в корзину 404 ошибка

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Вот пример товара. 
[http://shop2.wham.pro/product/угловой-корпус-дуб-молочный-двери-сте/](http://shop2.wham.pro/product/%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5/)
При нажатии на кнопку "добавить в корзину" выходит страница 404 и товар в корзину не добавляется. 
При этом кнопка это просто ссылка в которой

href=

```
http://shop2.wham.pro/product/угловой-корпус-дуб-молочный-двери-сте/?add-to-cart=108
```

И если мы на прямую перейдём по этой ссылке - то товар добавляется в корзину и нет 404 страницы...

Вопрос - как так? )

Comment: Нажимаю на кнопку правой кнопкой, выбираю "Открыть ссылку в новой вкладке" и работает, а при нажатии на кнопку - 404. Копирую кнопку в начало страницы - работает. Проверьте, какие обработчики висят на ссылках внутри описания продукта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На кнопке весит обработчик:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

http://shop2.wham.pro/wp-content/themes/shop3/js/my.js

```
$('.vkorziny').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    var i = $(this).parent();       
    document.location.href = $(i).next().attr('href');      
});
```

Поэтому и не получается просто перехода по ссылке.

Comment: спс. не заметил сам...